# LogicException Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure

Tags: laravel, routes, controls

I am getting this error when I do PHP artisan optimize.

The error:
[image]

The API route:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

This as start after I delete in my homeController this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

I don't want that the home controller just to logged-in users; I want everyone can see!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`php artisan optimize` also does `php artisan route:cache`. And You can't cache your routes if they are using Closure.

This is one of them.

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
       return $request->user();
});
```

What you can do is that. Change it to point to a `controller` class.

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', 'UserController@show');
```

And create another controller which is `UserController`. And you can have a method like this.

```php
public function show(Request $request)
{
    return $request->user();
}
```

This should work for you.